# Objective-C: How to check if a protocol-object is a special class

Tags: objective-c, interface, protocols

This Java-Code works:

```
public void executeCommand(ICommand cmd) { // ICommand is an Interface
 if (cmd.getClass().equals(LoginCommand.class)){

 }
}
```

But this Objective-C-Code doesn't work:

```
- (void)executeCommand: (id<Command>)cmd { // Command is a Protocol
 if ([cmd isKindOfClass:[LoginCommand class]]) {
  // WARNING: '-conformsToProtocol:' not found in protocol
 }
}
```

Comment: I want to comment that those two codes are not equivalent. your first code `cmd.getClass().equals(LoginCommand.class)` tests if the object is exactly that class; that would be like `[cmd isMemberOfClass:[LoginCommand class]]` in Objective-C. On the other hand, `[cmd isKindOfClass:[LoginCommand class]]` tests if the object is that class or a subclass, which is like `cmd instanceof LoginCommand` in Java

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you declare your protocol, tell it to inherit from the NSObject protocol like this:

```
@protocol Command <NSObject>
...
@end
```

reference is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html). NSObject is a base protocol that implements `-conformsToProtocol:`.